# Unable to connect to web service 'https' in .NET 7.0

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-7.0

In Visual Studio 2022, when I register my dependencies in `program.cs`, I cannot run my program and this error is displayed.

My project is built adhering to clean architecture, and I set my Web API project as the startup project.

I do not know what I should do...

Comment: It's impossible to help because there's no information in the question. HTTPS works out of the box, which can be proven by just creating a new web app project using one of the built-in templates and running it. HTTPS is used by default.

Comment: `this error is displayed` what error? Do you get a compilation error? An exception? Post the actual full error, preferably as text